# Which type of weather stripping is best for keeping smoke out of my house?

Tags: weatherstripping

I'm currently in process of figuring out what I can do to prevent my neighbor's cigarette smoke from entering my home (I'm open to any recommendations). One measure I am taking is weatherproofing my door; however as I visited Home Depot today, I realized there are a plethora of options: types of materials, different shapes, different groove patterns, etc. I asked the employee there, but he didn't seem too well-informed. Some of the materials I came across were rubber, silicone, foam. Shapes included a half-circle or half cylindrical shape, a rectangular shape. The rectangular one came with or without grooves. This is, of course, not a comprehensive list.

What would be the best shape, pattern, and material?

Comment: Can you ask your neighbor to refrain from smoking immediately next to your house? Or do they somehow produce such a prodigious amount of smoke that they saturate the neighborhood?

Comment: @Doresoom It's in an apartment, and the landlords don't care.